# Why does my function execute for every cell it has been set to every time I adjust my code?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a function that calculates values based on the input given. The function seems to work as expected.

I have been modifying some stuff in my other modules and userforms. I noticed a strange behavior. I put some Debug.prints in the code to see what's going on. My function executes for every cell it has been set to (20 pages with 300x this function) every time I adjust code in my workbook. It looks like this happens after a compile.

For the users it doesn't cause any trouble. But every time I try to test something in my code or add new code I have to wait for a bit unit all my functions to be recalculated.

Is there anyway to deal with this? Why is this happening? Maybe I should have done something different.

```vb
Function PhaseCalc3(ByVal Amount As Range, ByVal Phasecount As Range, ByVal StartPhase As Range, ByVal Value As Range) As Double
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim PhaseSum As Integer
Dim dTemp As Double

Result = 0

Debug.Print "Start PhaseCalc3"

Set Ws = ActiveSheet
If Ws.Name = "Overview" Then Exit Function

Select Case StartPhase
    Case 0, 1
        Select Case Phasecount
            Case 1
                PhaseSum = Int(Amount / 3) 'Iedere 3e fase
                dTemp = PhaseSum * Value
            Case 2
                PhaseSum = Int(Amount / 3) 'Iedere 3e fase
                PhaseSum = PhaseSum + Int((Amount + 1) / 3) 'iedere 2e fase
                dTemp = PhaseSum * Value
            Case 3
                dTemp = Amount * Value
        End Select
    Case 2
        Select Case Phasecount
            Case 1
                PhaseSum = Int((Amount + 1) / 3) 'iedere 2e fase
                dTemp = PhaseSum * Value
            Case 2
                PhaseSum = Int((Amount + 1) / 3) 'iedere 2e fase
                PhaseSum = PhaseSum + Int((Amount - 1) / 3) + 1 'Iedere 1e fase
                dTemp = PhaseSum * Value
            Case 3
                dTemp = Amount * Value
        End Select
    Case 3
        Select Case Phasecount
            Case 1
                PhaseSum = Int((Amount - 1) / 3) + 1 'iedere 1e fase
                dTemp = PhaseSum * Value
            Case 2
                PhaseSum = Int((Amount - 1) / 3) + 1 'Iedere 1e fase
                PhaseSum = PhaseSum + Int(Amount / 3) 'Iedere 3e fase
                dTemp = PhaseSum * Value
            Case 3
                dTemp = Amount * Value
        End Select
    Case 5
        Select Case Phasecount
            Case 2
            dTemp = Amount * Value
        End Select
    Case 6
        Select Case Phasecount
            Case 1, 2
                dTemp = Amount * Value
        End Select
        
End Select

PhaseCalc3 = dTemp
End Function

Here some screenshots of my workbook:  
[Print screen of my worksheet][1]

My intermediate window:  
[Intermediate window][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w4qU.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Fnw.png
```

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile It may be useful here

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns , Thanks for the tip. I did look into this, and have experimented with it. But making the function volatile or non volatile, does not seem to make a difference for me. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoutouts to FaneDuru in the comments. Every time the code changes in VBA it seems VBA needs to compile in order to work with it.

After every compile the whole workbook gets "Recalculated" Indeed settings this to manual / automatic can help during development. But like FaneDuru says "**This is the way Excel works!** That's why it is good to speed up your code, when it modifies something in cells, by setting Calculation on Manual, disabling events or screen updating for big ranges changes.

ill do my best to try and speed up my functions, to atleast make it a little more comfortable for myself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem does not stay in the code itself, if I correctly understood it. Being a UDF function, it is called each time as the `Calculation` event is triggered.

So, when you test something which will trigger the `Calculation` event (modifying cells value), you should use:

```
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     'your testing code
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

In this way, the calculation event is stopped for the testing duration. You can use F8, to run the code step by step without being brought to all the UDF functions code lines...

If an error makes the code stops in between the two lines, you must start the automatic calculations using a `Sub` containing a single code line:

```
Sub StartAutomaticCalculation()
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Or use an error handler configured to show the error number/ error description, followed by the above code line, but usually, in case of complex pieces of code, you need to see on which line the code raises the specific error...

Comment: @Merocky Did you understand what I tried suggesting? Did I understand what problem you have? It is, at least, polite to send some feedback when somebody tries helping you, even if the suggested solution does not solve your problem...

Comment: Hello Fane. Thank you for the suggestion, i have not tried your tip yet. Had a bussy weekend, ill give it a spin today. Ill keep you posted with the results.

Comment: Fane, Yes it does seem to trigger on a Calculation event, but i feel like this might be some sort of work around solution. Me having to set calculate to auto and manual all the time does feel like a pain in the ***. What i dont understand is why after a compile the WHOLE workbook gets recalculated. Even the cells that dont contain annything.

Comment: @Merocky Please, explain what do you mean by "compile the WHOLE workbook"? Do you press Compile VBAProject each time you modify something in code? Then, at what are you referring when write "every time i adjust my code"? To the function itself code, or at any other code trying to test? My answer was targeting the last supposition.

Comment: Well, i dont personally hit the "Compile" button in VBA. But i can imagine that Excel needs to Compile my code after a change in the code. Its just a hunch of me saying its in the compile, but what i notice is every time i change the code in my VBA script. No matter the which module or sheet or userform. Excel decides to recalculate every single cell that has a UDF in it. In my case my "Phasecalc1" Function. Unfortunately i have over 5000 cells filled with these functions. After a change it also only happens once. But the cells that recalculate sometimes dont even have values in them

Comment: @Merocky I am afraid that not any pieces of code triggers the calculate event. This is triggered only if the code in discussion makes some changes on the sheet. **This is the way Excel works**! That's why it is good to speed up your code, **when it modifies something in cells**, by setting Calculation on Manual, disabling events or screen updating for big ranges changes. If you name it 'work around' it is your choice, but you do not have much of a choice to overpass Excel  behavior, from this point of view, adapting the UDF function itself. Even without `Application.Volatile`, it is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer FaneDuru, i was afraid this was the case. That this is just the way Excel works, i was slightly hoping that somebody might have had a "Trick" to this. Ill see to it to speed up my own functions abit more, at least to speed it up for myself a little.